# Getting error while setting bitrate in CAN interface for ICS

Tags: android, setting, bitrate, can-bus

I am trying to set the bit-rate in i.Mx6 processor in android.
I am using iproute2 utility to set bitrate for CAN controller. The command used to set the bitrate is given below:

```
#ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000
```

While I am trying to set the bitrate in android using below command, I am getting error message.

The error message is given below:

> Garbage instead of arguments \"bitrate ...\". " "Try \"ip link help\""

I analysed and debugged inside the source code of this utility and compared with the Linux utility source. I found that the error was occurred in the system call dlsym().

```
   l = dlsym(dlh, buf);
    if (l == NULL)
            return NULL;
```

This function suppose to return some valid address. But in my case, its returning the NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to `external/iproute2/ip/Android.mk`

```
+LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--no-gc-sections
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Compile again, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

(1) (Android Source Code)/external/iproute2/ip/iplink.c

```
#define LIBDIR "/usr/lib/"
```

to

```
#define LIBDIR "/usr/lib"
```

(2) (Android Source Code)/external/iproute2/ip/Android.mk

```
+LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--no-gc-sections
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

PS. This bug only on Android ICS(4.0.4).